# How can i get "title" from this array?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

code ///

```
  https.get(`https://discordemoji.com/api?request=search&q=coffee}`, (resp) => {
let data = '';

resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
  data += chunk;
});

resp.on('end', () => {
  console.log(data)
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setTitle(`Search result for: "coffee}"`)
  .addField(`desc`, `link`)
  message.channel.send({embed});
});

  }).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
  });
```

from console.log(data) im getting this array:

```
[{"id":1857,"title":"Coffee","slug":"Coffee","description":"Good day!","category":1,"faves":4,"submitted_by":"Cristy","did":"339752841612623872"},{"id":432,"title":"AzuCoffee","slug":"AzuCoffee","description":"AzuCoffee is an anime style emoji","category":4,"faves":1,"submitted_by":"Kohai","did":"116218776495587329"},{"id":340,"title":"FeelsCoffeeMan","slug":"FeelsCoffeeMan","description":"FeelsCoffeeMan is a custom pepe style emoji","category":3,"faves":2,"submitted_by":"Kohai","did":"116218776495587329"}]
```

how can i get description for each id in array and post it to addfield?

Comment: `data.map(item => { item.description });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

const descriptions = parsedData.map(item => item.description)

[...].addField('desc', JSON.stringify(descriptions))
```

You can read more about `map`'s behaviour [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

EDIT: You need `JSON.stringify` because `desc` must be a string, not an Array.

Comment: i get this 
      const descriptions = data.map(item => item.description)
                                ^

TypeError: data.map is not a function

Comment: I didn't notice data was a string. I've updated the code to parse the string first as a Javascript object.

Comment: thx dude <3 do u also know how can i post each name in each addField?
like in "2"
https://i.imgur.com/u8VNJlq.png